Find the minimum number of connected subgraph that covers the whole digraph
I have a large directed graph, and I try to access every edge for this digraph. The problem is to minimize the number of the access (a connected subgraph is counted as one access). And it reduces to count the minimum number of connected subgraph that covers the whole digraph.
Is there any existing study or algorithm in this area?
I found some related topic such as finding the largest Eulerian subgraph, but it is different to find the minimum number of subgraphs.

This seems to be asking how to find the number of components in a graph.

Are you looking for weakly or strongly connected components? It seems that if you're trying to access all edges, it would be strongly connected, but I'm not sure I understood your comment.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)

@beaker Depends what OP means by 'connected subgraph'

To find the number of components in a graph using DFS ( Depth First Search ):
 - zero component count
 - unmark all vertices
 - WHILE unmarked vertices remain
    - increment component count
    - Select any unmarked vertex
       - mark selected vertex
       - Apply DFS starting from selected vertex, marking every visited vertex
 - END WHILE

